# Position UILabel in area relative to screen resolution

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I am trying to position UILabel relative to screen resolution (iPhone v iPad) so that the UILabel does not interfere with splash screen graphics at start-up. When the app was iPhone only, the label was located properly. Once the app was made universal, the Label interfered with the image on iPad (of course)

I am using the method below, which works fine, but it is not very forward thinking in terms of new devices and/or new screen resolutions.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient way to display the UILabel "Connecting to Server..." within the area circled in red on the attached image at the link below (I do not have auth to post images here yet)?

```
   UILabel *loadingLabel;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 350, self.window.frame.size.width, 20)];
}
else
{
    loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 700, self.window.frame.size.width, 20)];

}
loadingLabel.text = @"   Connecting to Server...";
loadingLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
loadingLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
loadingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

[Splash Screen](http://www.iautomate.com/content/splash.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `autoresizingMask` property to accomplish it.
set your origin.y on the label to be `self.window.bounds.size.height - 200` or so. Then set the `autoresizingMask` to be `UIViewAutoresizingMakFlexibleBottomMargin`